# Python--qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found

Tags: python-3.x, ssh, server, pyqt5

This code is a GUI with pyqt5. I run it through ssh on a server. But when I have run this code, it will have
"qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, webgl, xcb.

Aborted (core dumped)"

how could I deal with this error.

thanks in advance!

this is an image of that.

I try to run " sudo apt install libxcb-xinerama0 ", but it will have
"Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libxcb-xinerama0"

and I also try to install opencv-python-headless, but it still doesn't work out

Comment: Seems like a path or env problem. Could you share the details of how you are trying to run your program?

Comment: I run my code on my Pycharm through ssh connect my server. After connecting, I run it by ssh terminal. Do you mean the whole program? The main function is this:
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWin()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
others is just something about class and function, which I define by myself.

Comment: What I mean is: what are the environment variables of your running program, are you running in a docker container? - Those kinds of details.

Comment: Sorry, it's my fault. I don't run in a docker just on a server through the anaconda environment. The server system is Ubuntu 18.04 ;the Python is 3.8; the version of PyQt5 is 5.15.9; PyQt5-Qt5 is  5.15.9; the PyQt5-sip is 12.11.0, Should I set external tools in PyCharm for PyUIC?
I can run this program successfully in my local area, it mainly uses Yolov5 algorithm to detect something. Cuz my computer doesn't have Gpu, it work slowly the fps are very slow. So I have to run it on a server, which I have a lease with a platform. 
If you need other information, plz let me know. Thanks in advance.